# react-bootstrap modal is always mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

With the current implementation of react-bootsrap modal, it is required to render the modal and pass a `show` prop determining whether the modal is shown.
This means that if I build a component which wraps around `<Modal>`, it will be mounted from the first render, and all initialization logic will kick in, even though the modal is not shown.
Is there a way to avoid this?

- if I try to do `{this.state.showModal && <MyModal />}` instead of using the Modal `show` prop- I'm giving up the animation and proper hiding of the modal
- Currently I cannot use ReactRouter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you can't use React Router but the general way you approach is is not to put onShow/onHide logic in `componentWillMount` since that doesn't work.

Instead you can use the [transition lifecycle hooks](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#transitions-fade) or more simply just run your initialization logic when you set `show` to true or false.

Specifically if you wrap the modal to create `<MyModal>` maintain the same api and then do something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.show && !this.props.show) {
     //opening
  else if (!nextProps.show && this.props.show) {
     // closing
  }
}
```

Added comment:

If you don't like this approach I would suggest wrapping `<Modal.Body>` instead, and just plug it in to a Modal then your lifecycle hooks will act as you'd expect, since you are adding content to the part of the model that gets mounted on show.

Comment: Well... I feel like there's something wrong with the `<MyModal>` showing up in the React inspector DOM tree even though it shouldn't be initialized or shown

Comment: What you are seeing is the existance of a component in your render tree, its not actually a rendered thing, you'll notice there is no DOM anywhere, and besides the actual Modal gets rendered off the document body. More to the point tho that's failure in the Tooling, not the Component API

Also vanilla bootstrap requires _all_ the modal be in the DOM from the beginning, unless you do some fancy wrapping. so we are still doing better than that.